# Create a QTableWidgetItem with flags()

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I dont understand the Qt5 Documentation in the TableWidgetItem-Chapter.
I cant get the right parameters to set my freshly created TableCell as editable.
I've got this piece of code

```
for i, item in enumerate(event_desc, start=0):
        print(i, item)
        key   = QTableWidgetItem(list(event_desc)[i])
        value = QTableWidgetItem(event_desc[item])
        value.setFlags( * what's to insert here? * )
        tw.insertRow(i)
        tw.setItem(i, 0, key)
        tw.setItem(i, 1, value)
```

The first param should be *self, the 2nd one is named 'Union' (What does this mean? i cant go further, this param is missing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you must set a QTableWidgetItem as editable you must do:

```py
value.setFlags(value.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
```

The operator `|` allows to enable a flag, and instead the operation `& ~` disables them.

Comment: That `|` operator is a bitor function btw

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you use Pyside6 lib like me, the flag may be changed as,

Qt.ItemIsEditable or ~Qt.ItemIsEditable